# Java : Populate arraylist with for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

Currently I am trying to populate an ArrayList with a deck of cards,through the use of a for loop to get each card. It isn't quite working like I intended and was hoping for someone to point me in the right direction.

I'm seeing the following error:

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: The value must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the console's buffer size in that dimension.
```

My Deck Class:

```
public class Deck{
    private final int deckSize = 52;
    private final String[] suit = {"hearts", "clubs", "diamonds", "spades"};
    private final String[] face = {"Ace","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","Jack","Queen","King"};


    ArrayList<String> currentDeck = new ArrayList<String>(deckSize);


    public void getDeck(){
        for(int i=0; i<face.length; i++) {
            for(int j=0; j<suit.length; j++){
                String cards = face[i] + " of " + suit[j];
                currentDeck.add(cards);
            }
        }
    System.out.println(currentDeck);
    }
}
```

Main Class;

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printDeck();
    }

    public static void printDeck(){
        Deck deck = new Deck();  
        deck.getDeck();
    }
```

Comment: how did you intend it to work?

Comment: Which error appears? The logic works fine. In any case you need to declare the main method. Please send a reproducible example of your files

Comment: Please provide the expected output. The logic seems to be fine.

Comment: I have the deck class instantiated and the method called correctly in the main method as ```deck.getDeck```. I am receiving the error ```Exception:
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: The value must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the console's buffer size in that dimension.```

Comment: I expect the arraylist to be populated with all the cards of a deck of cards. For example Ace of Spades

Comment: Hi, @JB233 When you are editing the question please ensure that the originality of the question is not lost. You can put your edit part below the original question so that sequence of the question is tracked.

Regarding your current problem, you are putting the modulo operation in the wrong place. Continue adding to the currentDeck as you were doing before. After this loop finishes, you can iterate over currentDeck and print in the way you want.
Also, the condition should be changed to j%4 ==3 for your need.

Comment: This question is not yours. It's a question. If you have a "new problem", just ask a new question.

Comment: No problem, that was cleared up thanks don't need your input as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Deck deck = new Deck();
        deck.getDeck();
    }
}

class Deck {
    private final int deckSize = 52;
    private final String[] suit = {"hearts", "clubs", "diamonds", "spades"};
    private final String[] face = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};


    ArrayList<String> currentDeck = new ArrayList<String>(deckSize);


    public void getDeck() {
        for (int i = 0; i < face.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < suit.length; j++) {
                String cards = face[i] + " of " + suit[j];
                currentDeck.add(cards);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(currentDeck);
    }
}
```

I have copied your code only and this code works perfectly fine. I have just added the main method and called your method. And, the output that i am getting is

```
[1 of hearts, 1 of clubs, 1 of diamonds, 1 of spades, 2 of hearts, 2 of clubs, 2 of diamonds, 2 of spades, 3 of hearts, 3 of clubs, 3 of diamonds, 3 of spades, 4 of hearts, 4 of clubs, 4 of diamonds, 4 of spades, 5 of hearts, 5 of clubs, 5 of diamonds, 5 of spades, 6 of hearts, 6 of clubs, 6 of diamonds, 6 of spades, 7 of hearts, 7 of clubs, 7 of diamonds, 7 of spades, 8 of hearts, 8 of clubs, 8 of diamonds, 8 of spades, 9 of hearts, 9 of clubs, 9 of diamonds, 9 of spades, 10 of hearts, 10 of clubs, 10 of diamonds, 10 of spades, Jack of hearts, Jack of clubs, Jack of diamonds, Jack of spades, Queen of hearts, Queen of clubs, Queen of diamonds, Queen of spades, King of hearts, King of clubs, King of diamonds, King of spades]
```

I believe this is what you want.

Comment: Strange. Maybe an error with my environment. Thank you anyway!

Comment: Well, yes, the exception directly points to your console type. Print out each card in the deck on a separate line and the error will likely go away.

Comment: "Exception: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: The value must be greater than or equal to zero **and less than the console's buffer size in that dimension.**" Yes, that's a strange error, but it does rather clearly indicate what's wrong, right? I'm not trying to be condescending; I'm just pointing out that the contents of error messages are rather important. I mean iterate over the collection and print out each value rather than printing out the whole deck at once.

Answer (score 0):

Problem now resolved. Here is code for anyone having same problem!

```
class Deck {
    private final int deckSize = 52;
    private final String[] suit = {"hearts","diamonds", "clubs",  "spades"};
    private final String[] face = {"Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};

    ArrayList<String> currentDeck = new ArrayList<String>(deckSize);


    public void getDeck() {
        for (int i = 0; i < face.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < suit.length; j++) {
                if(j == 3){
                    String card = face[i] + " of " + suit[j];
                    currentDeck.add(card + "\n");
                }
                else{
                String cards = face[i] + " of " + suit[j];
                currentDeck.add(cards);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(currentDeck);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a code problem, but a result of the value of the environment's default configuration. Under Windows Server, you can change the default screen buffer size of your console to avoid it.